# Attach multiple files to a Google Classroom assignment?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

I'm trying to create a Classroom assignment with more than one file attached, here is my code with one file:

```
  Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.create({
        courseId: id,
        title : title,
        description : desc,
        workType : 'ASSIGNMENT',
        materials: [
          {
            driveFile:{
              driveFile: {
                id: fileId, 
                title: fileName
              },
              shareMode: "STUDENT_COPY"
            },
          }
        ],
        state : "PUBLISHED"
      }, id)
```

How do I add another file? I have tried to duplicate the 'driveFile' with no luck:

```
materials: [
      {
        driveFile:{
          driveFile: {
            id: fileId, 
            title: fileName
          },
          shareMode: "STUDENT_COPY"
        },
        driveFile:{
          driveFile: {
            id: fileId, 
            title: fileName
          },
          shareMode: "STUDENT_COPY"
        },
      }
    ],
```

Can't find any documentation or other questions on this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
{
  "workType": "ASSIGNMENT",
  "materials": [
    {
      "driveFile": {
        "driveFile": {
          "id": "FILE_ID",
          "title": "TestingFile"
        },
        "shareMode": "STUDENT_COPY"
      }
    },
    {
      "driveFile": {
        "driveFile": {
          "id": "FILE_ID",
          "title": "Sample Docs"
        },
        "shareMode": "STUDENT_COPY"
      }
    }
  ],
  "description": "Assignment 1 &2",
  "title": "Assignment"
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

I tried it using the [Method: courses.courseWork.create](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/create) Try this API to help me construct the request correctly.

Hope this helps.